# Is there a term for a word created by adding a letter to an existing word?

Tags: terminology, orthography

It's possible to generate English words by adding letters to existing words—for instance:

- last > **b**last
- utility > **f**utility

Is there a term for this, i.e. when a word is created by adding a letter to an existing word?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about English language games rather than usage.

Comment: OK, though I don't see why playful usage isn't usage—e.g., [Futility Closet](http://www.futilitycloset.com/). Seems like a grumpy rule.

Comment: Why would such a concept exist?

Comment: @vladkornea  Might it be because it is part of being human to want to invent words for things?

Comment: An extra syllable added is *catalectic*. Just a letter might be described as a form of *augmentation,* though *augment* particularly applies to initial a- or e-.  *Accretion* (4) 'an extraneous addition (earliest use 1654). *(ShorterOxford.)*

Comment: @Edwin: Actually, he's asking whether there is a term that defines an *action* that relates to language games. It's a vocabulary question, really.

Comment: @Misha There have been numerous Meta discussions about whether allowing single-word requests is in the best interests of the site. While I myself wouldn't adopt the 'ban them all' stance, the obviously ludicrous ('is there a word meaning not being able to jump a 6 foot ditch with your pockets full of molybdenum?') should not be allowed, and the  very-unlikely-to-exist ('is there a word for the sudden onset of arctic water flowing through your showerhead when Mom decides to engage the hot water cycle on the washer and/or dishwasher ?'  – alpha dictionary) barred if having little potential use.

Comment: ... You have forced me into unsloppifying my given close-vote reason. Sadly, trying to forestall answers such as the daub below takes far too much time.

Comment: If you want the name of the game, it is [*word pyramid*](https://books.google.ca/books?id=mIPOCQAAQBAJ&pg=PA2&lpg=PA2&dq=word+pyramid+adding+letter&source=bl&ots=fKQV5mkTrC&sig=C7SCk13FRd9E6Jq_W04InXbA92U&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CD8Q6AEwBmoVChMI7bbV3_LkxgIVDhKSCh0Sog3O#v=onepage&q=%22word%20pyramid%22&f=false).

Comment: @Misha Rosnach I'd have thought that you could see the connection between 'relates [only, as far as I can see] to [obscure] word games – _if_ it exists, which is doubtful' and 'very-unlikely-to-exist' ... +  'having little potential use [amonst most anglophones]' . It takes a lot of time trying to avoid trivia like "Single letter concatenative morphology". _You_ find a better close-vote descriptor. I fully understand why some contributors fully support the anonymous downvote option.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Meh.  I prefer your single-word issue that uses the *molybdenal nearsixer* and the *motherly iceblast* as examples.  I think it's a stronger argument, and I actually agree.

Comment: When I've a tricky window-surround at extreme reach to paint (I'm still recovering), I can do without non-essential demands in other directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would call it, adding a prefix or suffix.

But **last** and **blast** are **not at all** related whatsoever. And the `b` is

### not a prefix

It's not possible

### Unless maybe you're making a program to generate words for Scrabble.

And even then, no such rule exists.  You cannot just generate a word by adding a letter to it.  If anything, you have just added a

### "complementary letter"?

by accident.

Answer (score 2):

"Single letter concatenative morphology"? That's what a linguist might call this, but only when word stems are augmented in a standard way (like appending an s to make a noun plural).

I doubt there is a term for converting words into unrelated words through trial and error.